# Looking for examples of good svn commit comments

Tags: svn, comments

I just started my own svn server to develop my application. I am learning English and I want to write comments on svn commits in English. What words, patterns, terms and tenses should I use?

What are common words on svn comments? Fix, bug, feature? I'm looking for good style to get good style and good habits from the start.

Comments in code are also important but I think it is more examples and books about it.

Comment: Voted to move this to programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at good public projects in SVN, for example: Google Chrome.
I opened Repo-browser of TortoiseSVN, with the url: http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src
Then right click on src folder, "Show Log", and you see all the commit messages.
See attached image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think its best if you read up on svn. This can be a good start http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.html

On the other hand, there is no fixed way to commit comments. It is encouraged to commit changes after a days work with all the changes made to that version of the code. You can include the bugs that remain, bugs fixed and work left to be done. It really depends on you. But the more detail you put in, the easier it becomes when you have to sort through different revisions.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the repository where the [Subversion code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/) itself is hosted:

```
svn log -r {2011-01-01}:{2011-02-01} http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/
```